# Loading input with method

Tags: java, methods

I have been looking for a way to load input through a method so that the user can operate the menu.

So far I have this:

```
public static char printMenu(){
  char option = ' ';
  Scanner load = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("\nMENU\nc - blah blah blah");
  option = load.next().charAt(0);
  System.out.println(option);
  return option;
}
```

However when I call it here:

```
 System.out.println("You entered: "+storage);
  char menuOpt = ' ';
  while(menuOpt != 'q'){
     menuOpt = printMenu();
```

and enter in the letter c and then q. It gives me:

```
You entered: Hello my name is Kong.

MENU
blah blah blah

Choose an option:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at AuthoringAssistant.printMenu(AuthoringAssistant.java:10)
    at AuthoringAssistant.main(AuthoringAssistant.java:36)
```

I thought that since it is a char return type that I would be able to use it? I clearly see I am wrong. What am I overlooking?

Thank you.

For Aify:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class AuthoringAssistant {


   public static char printMenu(){
      char option = ' ';
      Scanner load = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("\nMENU\nc - Number of non-whitespace characters\nw - Number of words\nf - Find text\nr - Replace all !'s\ns - Shorten spaces\nq - Quit\n\nChoose an option:");
      option = load.nextLine().charAt(0);
      System.out.println(option);
      return option;
   }

   public static int getNumOfNonWSCharacters(String storage){
      int n = 0;
      int amount = 0;
      for(n=0;n<storage.length();++n){
         if(storage.charAt(n) != ' '){
            ++amount;
         }
      }
      return amount;
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String storage = "";
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a sample text:");
      storage = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("You entered: "+storage);
      char menuOpt = ' ';
      while(menuOpt != 'q'){
         menuOpt = printMenu();
         if(menuOpt == 'c'){
            int amount = getNumOfNonWSCharacters(storage);
            System.out.println("Number of non-whitespace characters: "+amount);
         }

      }


      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by you enter "c" then "q"? Did you enter "cq" and press the enter key or did you do "c" enter "q" enter?

Comment: @aify I did "c" enter then "q" enter but it does this right after entering c. It does not print the menu again.

Comment: Can you post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: it works well.. what is your problem?

Comment: @MoustafaElsaghier If I enter c, it is supposed to load that menu again but its giving me the error message and not passing the char to the variable.

Comment: @Aify I added the full code above.

Comment: I copied your example and ran it on my local using the input you described. It ran fine.

Comment: @nobetw I guess its just my system. Everyone I give it to is saying the same thing.

Comment: @DamaniAPhilip Have you recompiled? That's all I can think of.

Comment: @nobetw I have sooo many times. Im going to go take a run and then come get back at it.

Comment: it works well with me, I just copied your code in netbeans and it run well

Comment: @DamaniAPhilip Sounds good. Maybe give the machine a reboot as well. I'm puzzled as to why it's not working for you.